# htaccess rewrite not rewriting correctly in address bar

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ http://localhost/website/sale/phones/index.php?type=$1&location=$2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$                 http://localhost/website/sale/phones/index.php?type=$1
```

I have the links set up like this

```
if (!isset($_GET['type'])) {
    $query = "SELECT type, url FROM {$phones}";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($phone = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<li><a href="'. $phone['url'] .'/">'. $phone['type'] .'</a></li>';
    }
} else {
    $query = "SELECT location, url FROM locationstwo LIMIT 100";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    while($location = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<li><a href='. $_GET['type'] .'/'. $location['url'] .'/>'. $location['location'] .'</a></li>';
    }   
}
```

?>

the url is displayed as localhost/website/sale/phones/phonetype/location/ at the bottom left corner as wanted

but once the link is clicked, the address bar comes up with the ?variables

localhost/website/sale/phones/index.php?type=phone-type&location=location
when what i really want is localhost/website/sale/phones/phone-type/location/

is it something to do with the .htaccess?

saying that, when EXPLICITLY typed with /phone-type/location/ it passes the parameters, so htaccess is working but the address bar just displays them with the ?varialbe.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to incorrect rewrite rules. Make sure to use paths without domain as target. Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /website/sale/phones/index.php?type=$1&location=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ /website/sale/phones/index.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ahhh that seems to have worked! THANKS! However, my stylesheets seemed to have changed path. Can that be fixed using <base href>? Thanks

Comment: You can use `<base href>` tag OR better use absolute paths for css, js, images i.e. starting with `/` or `http://`